# How can I Insert data into SQL Server 2008 of any file in bits format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

Please reply as soon as possible. Because I am working on a project right now and I need the solution of this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should mayne rather have a look at using

[FILESTREAM Storage in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109(SQL.100).aspx)

[FileStream Data Type : SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manisblog/archive/2007/10/21/filestream-data-type-sql-server-2008.aspx)